# How can i hide and show div if radio button checked in jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

in wordpress i create some metaboxes for post formats, so when user click one radio button or its already checked the metabox show display.

here is the codes i tried some jquery but i m not good with jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="post-formats-select">
    <input type="radio" id="post-format-0" class="post-format" value="0" name="post_format" />
    <label class="post-format-standard">Standard</label>

    <input type="radio" id="post-format-chat" class="post-format" value="chat" name="post_format" />
    <label class="post-format-chat">Chat</label>

    <input type="radio" id="post-format-gallery" class="post-format" value="gallery" name="post_format" checked="checked" />
    <label class="post-format-gallery">Gallery</label>

    <input type="radio" id="post-format-video" class="post-format" value="video" name="post_format" />
    <label class="post-format-video">Video</label>    
</div>

<div class="meta-box-sortables">
    <div id="inpost_chat_box" class="postbox">
        Chat Box
    </div>    

    <div id="inpost_gallery_box" class="postbox">
        Gallery Box
    </div>

    <div id="inpost_video_box" class="postbox">
        Video Box
    </div>    
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#inpost_chat_box, #inpost_gallery_box, #inpost_video_box').hide();

var formats = $('#post-formats-select input');
formats.on('change', function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked').val() == 'gallery' ) {
        $('#inpost_gallery_box').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: this is how you want http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9c4/141/

Comment: can you put your code in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) as it returns a boolean not the jQuery object. There is not `.val()` method within `.is()` so it's probably throwing a:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: undefined is not a function

if you check your browser's console.

Try breaking down the conditional into two statements like so:

```
formats.on('change', function(){
    if( this.checked && this.value == 'gallery' ) {
        $('#inpost_gallery_box').show();
    }
});
```